# jQuery effect for multiple items with same id

Tags: jquery

I want to apply a hover fade to multiple elements whose ID is #front-overlay.  This code currently works only for the first element with that ID.  Thanks for your help.

`$("#front-overlay").mouseenter(function() {

  $(this).fadeTo("fast", 0.8);

  $(this).css("color","#fff");

});

$("#front-overlay").mouseleave(function() {

  $(this).fadeTo("fast", 0.3);`

Comment: There are no *"multiple items with same id"* in HTML. If you have them, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Don't know what kind of HTML you write, my friend...  Anyway, I'll answer my own question: use the element tag in addition to its ID.  That is, `$("li#front-overlay").mouseenter(function()...` will do the trick.  Note that I was using `<li id="front-overlay">` for the items on which I wanted to apply jQuery effects.

Comment: **No**.  Just don't use duplicate IDs.

Comment: You shouldn't have multiple items with the same id. Use classes instead.

Comment: I see.  Thanks to SLaks and Trevor. I will try to use a class instead.  Been fiddling to get this to work way too long...

Comment: @Zbot I write the kind of HTML where you don't use the same ID for multiple elements. Much like everybody else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have multiple items with the same ID.
If you do, it won't work properly.

Instead, use classes.

Comment: This needs to be re-defined in the W3 spec in _really huge big red letters_.

Comment: @Jam: You seem to be under the sadly-mistaken impression that developers read specs.

Comment: That I am, that I am. Maybe it should be laser-engraved onto every object every developer owns, along with a few other important points?

Comment: Yes.  Good luck with that.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Change your `id="front-overlay"` with `class="front-overlay"` and then use the following code (changed the # sign with . for classe)

```
$(".front-overlay").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).fadeTo("fast", 0.8);
    $(this).css("color","#fff");
});
$(".front-overlay").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).fadeTo("fast", 0.3);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just applying a little logic- (all comments above are certainly correct- id's are *only* to be used once per page for example the header, footer etc).

If jquery adheres to such standards (hopefully someone else could clarify this??) then try the following:

```
$(".front-overlay").mouseenter(function() {
$(this).fadeTo("fast", 0.8);
$(this).css("color","#fff");
});
$(".front-overlay").mouseleave(function() {
$(this).fadeTo("fast", 0.3);`
```

You would then, of-course have to change all your html id's into class="front-overlay" and remember to also update your css file!

Comment: oopse sorry looks like @wasimbhalli beat me! I gues jquery *does* keep to such standards? great